# Utilizar misma GPU por PyTorch y TensorFlow a la vez

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda

Muy buenas.

No tengo unos conocimientos profundos sobre cómo funciona la GPU en PyTorch o en TensorFlow. Estoy ejecutando YOLOv3 en PyTorch, cuando me detecta un objeto lo envío a un modelo VGG19 programado en TensorFlow. Sin embargo, si uso la GPU en ambos modelos no me deja. Al parecer, CUDA no permite que haya otra ejecución en paralelo. ¿Es esto cierto? ¿Habría alguna manera de que dejara hacerlo en la misma GPU o tengo que programar el modelo VGG19 en PyTorch para que así me deje?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!